# The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'. Parameter name

Tags: xml, wcf, web-config, wcf-endpoint

i went through some previous questions, but i think am missing somewhere, As WCF is totally new for me.

web.config in WCF service application

```
  <service behaviorConfiguration="BehaviourName" name="ProjectName.ServiceName">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ProjectName.IServiceName">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://aaa.bbbbbb.com/IISDeployedFolderName"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
  ....................
  .....................

  <behavior name="BehaviourName">
    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
  </behavior>
  ............................
  ..........................
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="secureHttpBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  ..........................
  .........................
  <protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="https" />
  </protocolMapping>
  ............................
  ..............................
```

In MVC application, other application am consuming above code service.

added service reference with default settings and automatically generated endpoint address with http, if i change it to https it's breaking with error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WCF, we should configure an extra service endpoint for `HTTPS` protocol, which requires the transport layer security mode.

```
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
        <!--please pay attention to that apply the binding configuration by means of bindingConfiguration property.-->
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" bindingConfiguration="mybinding"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="mybinding">
          <security mode ="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

The below configuration supports both HTTP protocol and HTTPS protocol.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
        <!--please pay attention to that apply the binding configuration by means of bindingConfiguration property.-->
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" bindingConfiguration="mybinding"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="mybinding">
          <security mode ="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

We could also use `ProtocolMapping` section to simplify the configuration. The below configuration support both HTTP and HTTPS protocol.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Official document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/simplified-configuration
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thank you it helped me -@Abraham